# c# position of words in a user generated array sentence

Tags: c#, .net

New to the site, so apologies for breaking any protocols etc.  I have read the guidelines.

I have had a long look around for a solution to a slight problem that i have.  I simply want to return the location of all words in a sentence for example.  Due to me wanting the user to generate a sentence, then a regex match is unhelpful. I have tried IndexOf, but have not been able to make much progress.

"Stackoverflow helps developers, as it helps with development tasks, and is a useful developers resource."

" 1 2 **3** 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 **3** 15"

The positions are returned and as developers is a duplicate word, it refers back to its original position of the word.

```
int wordPosition = 0;
string userSentence;

Console.Write("Input sentence");
userSentence = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write(String.IndexOf(wordPosition));
Console.WriteLine(userSentence.Substring(userSentence.IndexOf(wordPosition)));
```

Comment: There is no library method that I know that does this. Do you have any code you have tried to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is probably to create a dictionary of the words you've encountered so far. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> words = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then, parse each word one at a time:

```
index = 0
/* this doesn't work: replace it with logic to split the sentence into words */
foreach (var word in sentence) { 
  if (!words.ContainsKey(word)) {
    words.Add(word, index) 
  }
  Console.WriteLine(words[word]);
  index++;
}
```

I'm assuming you can write code to iterate over the words in your sentence? Also, this solution treats words with different casing as different. If you want it to be case insensitive, you could convert everything to lower case when searching and inserting in the dictionary, although a preferable approach is to use a case-insensitive comparer when creating the dictionary:

```
var words = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: In general, prefer converting to upper case. There are languages (e. g. Greek), where one and the same letter (Greek: Sigma) can have more than one representation in lower case.

Comment: In general, I prefer using a case-insensitive comparer since it handles all of this without having to know which languages have these quirks and whether or not they go both directions. But I offered this for simplicity.

Comment: Truth, that's actually the way to go. Why didn't you write that in your answer, though?

Comment: "But I offered this for simplicity." When people ask questions to indicate they may not be particularly familiar with programming, I try not to obfuscate the problem at hand by providing the academically perfect solution. I don't know whether the user wants to differentiate on case, and I don't wish to confuse the issue. Once he has mastered the algorithm, it is a short jump to make it work for other languages. But I can include it as a comment.

Comment: Seems to me that the nicer solution even is the simpler one... Still the point remains: If converting, you should convert to upper case for given reason. Sorry for being penetrant, but I prefer hinting people to the "correct" way right from the start...

Comment: Thank you for your replies so far.
I have used .ToUpper and also other elements to ensure the string does not contain unwanted char's etc.  I am able to return positions of words, but not all words in the sentence.  I have looked at various collections, such as lists etc, but i would expect it to be easily achieved simply in a string array, but just haven't been able to get it working correctly yet.  I also have duplications sorted, but again just stuck on this little detail.

Comment: @Aconcagua Converting to upper case isn't the "correct way." If correctness is your goal, you should have suggested a case insensitive comparison. Of course, if absolute correctness is always your goal, be prepared for a lifetime of never writing any code.

Comment: You might have an additional list - each time a word is contained, you add the index already contained to the list - and if not, you add it newly as in the answer and add the new index to the list, too.

Comment: @Old_Joe Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx as starter. You give it an array of characters it can use to split the words on and it will split at those delimiters. Googling: "split a sentence up into words" should return a nearly limitless list of ideas.

Comment: @jeremy, thanks again for replying.  I have used .split etc and that is reflected in the locals window when debugging.  I will go have a read of the URL that you kindly provided.

Comment: @JeremyWest That's why I placed it into quotation marks. I do not disagree that the really correct way is using the caseinsensitive comparer. But if you cannot use it for wichever reason (e. g. because of using another language), you should convert to upper instead of lower case.

Comment: @Aconcagua Except that Turkish, for example, sometimes does unexpected things when converting to upper case. Converting to upper case may be better for Greek, but it isn't better for everything. It is wrong to pretend it is superior in any problem unless it is clearly part of the requirements that it should work for Greek but need not work for languages where ToUpper is wrong, which would be an odd requirement indeed.

Comment: @Aconcagua Perhaps I'm the one being picky here, but I think one should expect this when being overly pedantic. If you're going to correct my suggestion of a potential solution to a problem that isn't central to the original question, you should at least correct it correctly.

Comment: @JeremyWest Wherever I came accross (and that was not few - Greek was only the one example among many that remained in my mind), converting to upper case was common sense, so my comments. Now I've learned something new myself (thanks for the hint...). Still, converting to lower does not seem to help either - is this right? Then Turkish would be the 'neither-nor-example'...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ-heavy solution I came up with. I made a few assumptions, though:

- We don't care about trailing punctuation
- We don't care about numeric "words"

I'm not sure what value calling `Substring` would be, as we're keeping track of the word index, not the character index.
Also, in your example, "helps" is a duplicated word as well.

```
void Main()
{
    var sentence = "Stackoverflow helps developers, as it helps with development tasks, and is a useful developers resource. A non-trivial solution involves edge cases.";

    var wordTracker = new WordTracker(sentence);

    wordTracker.WriteAll();
    Console.WriteLine(wordTracker.IndexOf("developers")); //Writes 3
    Console.WriteLine(wordTracker.IndexOf("notfound")); //Writes -1
    Console.WriteLine(wordTracker.IndexOf("non-trivial")); //Writes 17
    Console.WriteLine(wordTracker.WordAt(13)); //Writes "useful"
}

public class WordTracker {
    private static readonly Regex _wordRegex = new Regex(@"[\S]*\w");
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _wordPositions = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private List<WordPosition> _words;

    public WordTracker(string input) {
        BuildWordPositions(input);
    }

    public int IndexOf(string word) {
        int index;
        return _wordPositions.TryGetValue(word, out index)
            ? index + 1 //From the example, we're 1-indexed
            : -1;
    }

    public string WordAt(int index)
    {
        index = index - 1; //From the example, we're 1-indexed
        if (index < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Index must be positive");
        if (index >= _words.Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

        return _words[index].Word;
    }

    public void WriteAll() {
        foreach (var kvp in _wordPositions) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    private void BuildWordPositions(string input)
    {
        _words = input.Split(' ')
            .Select((m, i) => new WordPosition(i, m)).ToList();
        var wordGroups = _words.GroupBy(m => m.Word);

        foreach (var wordGroup in wordGroups) {
            _wordPositions.Add(wordGroup.Key, wordGroup.First().Index);
        }
    }

    private class WordPosition
    {
        public WordPosition(int index, string word) {
            Index = index;
            Word = _wordRegex.Match(word).Value.ToLower();
        }

        public int Index { get; private set; }
        public string Word { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time and effort in providing that code, i need to go out right now, so i will provide some further feedback tomorrow and allocate a correct answer etc.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take it that since you say words, you want to ignore whitespace.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

int placement = 1;
Regex.Split("your string here", @"\s+").ToList().ForEach
(x => { Console.WriteLine(x + "[" + placement + "]"); placement++; });
```

Comment: Had something very similar for removing whitespace and punctuation, thank you for your comment.